# How can I allow multiple Date formats in Ruby on Rails for csv file import?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a birthday column in my csv that should allow user to input **multiple date formats** and then the file be imported via web page. At the moment the column is only set to one type of format; `:birthday => (Date.strptime(row[2], "%mm/%dd/%YY") rescue nil),`.
Is it possible to have multiple date formats?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [`Date.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) instead:

> Parses the given representation of date and time, and creates a date object.
>
> If the optional second argument is true and the detected year is in the range “00” to “99”, considers the year a 2-digit form and makes it full.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Date.parse('2001-02-03')          #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
> Date.parse('20010203')            #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
> Date.parse('3rd Feb 2001')        #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
> ```

If you need more control, you could always define your own parsing method.

Comment: I've tried `Date.parse` but it didn't work for me. Perhaps you can give me an example using my code from the question? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, Date.parse worked perfectly, I just didn't write it correctly the first time. So, doing this, `(Date.parse(row[2]) rescue nil)` was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Rails' DateTime tries to detect the formatting automatically. It will detect the following formats: `mm/dd/yy` or `dd-mm-yy` or `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Otherwise you'll have to build your own method that tries different parsing with the formats present on the file.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the Rails formats, what I really need is a way of implementing all of those three formats into one method or whatever that maybe. This brings me to a case statement that could check on a format and then parse the date into a table, but I haven't tried this yet.